# onchange event to reload page and call another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML page where I have a select box with some elementa in the drop down. 
Each time the element is selected through the onchange event a tree structure is loaded based on the element selected.

The problem I am facing is 
I select one element from drop down and the structure is loaded fine in HTML page.
But I select another element onchange event works but it overlaps with the first.

How to reload the page on an onchange event and also call the function to load the structure?

This is my code

```
<select id ="sid"  onchange="fnLoadStructure(this);">
<option> select </option>
</select>
```

JavaScript code

```
function fnLoadStructure (selectedele){
// code to generate structure
}
```

I tried to use location.reload() in my fnLoadStructure but even before the results are loaded the page is refreshed.

How do I solve this?

Comment: what is that point after "sid"? In any case, if you reload the document you go back to its original status, unless you use a cookie to store something of the current session or something like that. How are you loading the data? what is the desired output?

Comment: Can you explain this clearly - `But I select another element onchange event works but it overlaps with the first`

Comment: First time I select an element from drop down desired output loads fine.Second time I select element output loads but overlapping with the first. I want the first output to erase and second output to be shown.